# How to scrape multiple URLs with same parse using Scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

Hi I am having a problem regarding my spider script, I wanted to make my script readable as possible and I wanted to save code as much as possible. Is it possible to use same parse on different URL?

I wanted to scrape 10 items per page only and save it on different items function in `items.py`

Here's my code

```
def start_requests(self):  #I have 3 URL's Here
    yield scrapy.Request('https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/post-ratings/6/posts', self.parse) #Url 1
    yield scrapy.Request('https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/post-ratings/7/posts', self.parse) #Url 2
    yield scrapy.Request('https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/post-ratings/1/posts', self.parse) #Url 3


def parse(self, response): #My logic is something like this    
    if Url == Url1:
        item = TmcnfSpiderItem()
    elif Url == Url2:
        item = TmcnfSpiderItem2()
    elif Url == Url3:
        item = TmcnfSpiderItem3()

    if count <= 9:
        count += 1
        info = response.css("[id^='fc-post-" + postno_only +"']")
        author = info.xpath("@data-author").extract_first()
        item['author'] = author      
        yield item
     else:
         #Move to next URL and perform same parse
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to pass all data from `start_requests`, like here:

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = (
        ('https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/post-ratings/6/posts', TmcnfSpiderItem),
        ('https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/post-ratings/7/posts', TmcnfSpiderItem2),
        ('https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/post-ratings/1/posts', TmcnfSpiderItem3),
    )
    for url, itemclass in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'itemclass': itemclass}) 

def parse(self, response):
    item = response.meta['itemclass']()
```

So you pass your item classname for each url, and in `parse` function create new element of this class.